# I can't see anonymous access menu in SharePoint 2010

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I'm so confused because after enabling anonymous access in central administration panel on SharePoint 2010, I can't see the Anonymous access in the Site Setting -> Site Permissions

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have more than one zone for the webApp? If so are you in the right zone?

Comment: Have you followed the right steps? Please go here (http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010) to verify.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you did not set the anonymous access policy in Central Admin. This seems to be a commonly forgot step in enabling anonymous access.

If you look at the [article](http://www.topsharepoint.com/enable-anonymous-access-in-sharepoint-2010) provided by saumlin you will see that step described in steps 5 and 6.